# Restoring vendor directory in a laravel 5.1 project with composer

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.1

I rebuilt my vm development and cloned my laravel project from its repo. When I tried to hit the site, I got the fatal error that the `vendor` directory was missing in the project root. Sure enough, `vendor` is listed in the `.gitignore`.

I've looked over the installation instructions, and I don't see where it explicitly says how to build the vendor directory. I'm new to this, so I'm supposing it's done with composer (I started this site about a month ago and my recollection of the installation is a little fuzzy).

How do I build laravel's vendor directory with composer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to run `composer install`.

Comment: ah, @dotctor, he is the author